# How To Make reCaptcha Pass HTML5 validation using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha which renders an iframe and a text area into a div on my page:

However, the recaptcha embeds an iframe with `scrolling=no` and 'frameborder=0' both of which fail html5 validation.

HTML5 specs say these attributes should be replaced using CSS but I am unable to hide the scrollbars on the iframe with CSS.

For reference, here is my markup:

```
<div id="g_recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha">
    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

To render the captcha:

```
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onCaptchaLoaded&render=explicit';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
```

The which fires the following callback:

```
    window.onCaptchaLoaded = function() {
        grecaptcha.render("g_recaptcha", {
            'sitekey' : '6LeveRUUAAAAAMRdgfWYWDzGd1iGYPSB_TIvg7nN',
            'callback' : captchaValidated,
            'expired-callback' : captchaExpired
        });

        $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr("title", "reCaptcha response");
        $('#g_recaptcha iframe').removeAttr("frameborder").css("border", "none")
                .removeAttr("scrolling").css("overflow", "hidden");

    }
```

As you can see I am trying to use query to remove the invalid HTML5 attributes and replace them with their CSS counter parts.

Is there more CSS I need here to hide the scrollbars or is there a better way to make reCaptcha HTML5 compliant?

Comment: I'm all for writing valid code, but in this case ... It is inserted via script anyway, so it is not gonna fail validation of your original HTML code; browsers are massively tolerant in this regard, so these attributes will just "work"; and finally, when CSS is used to achieve or forbid page scrolling, that happens by applying `overflow` to the html or body element - both of which you have no scripting access to here, because the iframe contains content from a different domain. So even if you kill those attributes, you will not be able to replace them with corresponding CSS functionality.